# node server (without Express) does not render image and it keeps loading at localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services

[image]I created a server without express and I'm trying to server a simple static webpage on localhost
here is my code :

```
const fs = require('fs')
const url = require('url');
const hostname = 'localhost'
const port = 3000;
const path = require ('path');
const http = require ('http')

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url.match (/.css$/)) {
        let cssPath = path.join (__dirname, req.url)

        let cssReadStream = fs.createReadStream (cssPath, 'UTF-8')
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader ("Content-Type", "text/css");
        cssReadStream.pipe (res)
    }
    if (req.url === "/") {
        fs.readFile("./index.html", 'UTF-8', (err, data) => {
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
            res.end(data);

        })
    }
    if (req.url.match (/.jpg$/)) {
        let jpgPath = path.join (req.url)
        console.log (jpgPath)
        let jpgReadStream = fs.createReadStream (jpgPath, 'UTF-8')
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader ('Content-Type', 'image/jpg')
        jpgReadStream.pipe (res)
    }
})

server.listen (port, hostname, () => {
    console.log ('server start')
})
```

first of all, it can display the HTML and CSS, however, localhost just keeps on loading after HTML and CSS displayed. Second of All, the image cannot be display (a instagram icon name icon.jpg).
the end result should look something like this:

I guess it has something to do with the favicon thing, but how do i fix it?

[image]

Comment: Open in chrome go to network tab and take a screenshot and post the pic in the question

Comment: Hi i just added a image

Comment: i didn't see any image requests, are you sure they are there in the Html? can you post relevant part of the /index.htm file?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use response.send() function which will be used to send the response back

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url.match (/.css$/)) {
        let cssPath = path.join (__dirname, req.url)

        let cssReadStream = fs.createReadStream (cssPath, 'UTF-8')
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader ("Content-Type", "text/css");
        cssReadStream.pipe (res)
        res.send("your data")
    }
    if (req.url === "/") {
        fs.readFile("./index.html", 'UTF-8', (err, data) => {
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
            res.end(data);
            res.send("your data")
        })
    }
    if (req.url.match (/.jpg$/)) {
        let jpgPath = path.join (req.url)
        console.log (jpgPath)
        let jpgReadStream = fs.createReadStream (jpgPath, 'UTF-8')
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader ('Content-Type', 'image/jpg')
        jpgReadStream.pipe (res)
        res.send("your data")    
       }
})
```